# What is this syntax html`...`?

Tags: javascript

Here's a snippet from polymer [docs](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/start)

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'

class Component extends LitElement {
  render () {
    return html`<p>A paragraph</p>`
  }
}

customElements.define('app-layout', Component)
```

I'm confused with this line `` return html`<p>A paragraph</p>` ``

`typeof html` gives me `function`, so it must be some sort of function infocation. `html('<p>A paragraph</p>')` throws an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.strings.join is not a function`

Comment: It's a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Polymer3 official [documentation](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#templateobject)

> The template getter must return an instance of HTMLTemplateElement. Use the `html` helper function to generate an HTMLTemplateElement instance from a JavaScript template literal. (You can import the html helper from the polymer-element.js module.)

Here `html` is a helper function. The [**Polymer.html**](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#inherit) helper introduced in Polymer 2.4 makes template extension a little simpler.